# Spring and hibernate Validation

Tags: database, hibernate, spring-mvc, data-binding

My project is on Spring and Hibernate,
I have a table address which is related to userDetails Table and in the registration form i am using Address table for commandName as shown below

```
<form:form action="register" commandName="Address" method="post" >
```

I am using validation and my controller is as below

```
public String getRegister( @ModelAttribute("address")@Validated Address        address, BindingResult result,HttpServletRequest request,Map<String, Object> model)
 {

if (result.hasErrors()) {
    System.out.println("in error");
    return "login";
}
else 
{
}
}
```

Binding result is showing error for address entity fields only where as not show error of user_details entity even they are in relation.

Please help me. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

> you can use JSR303 Validation for this,if you using variables of user_details table in address then you can use @Transient annotation for this.

```
suppose you have address model like
```

Address:

```
private int addressId;
@Transient
private int userId // variable of user_detail model
```

and you use

> @Valid annotation instead of @Validated